# final classes and inheritance in swift (Vapor)

Tags: swift, inheritance, vapor

First of all I know the purpose of final classes : no other class should inherit from it. It also delivers some extra speed as the compiler can make direct calls.

I'm writing a project in Vapor, the Swift web frame work. I want to split up the project into reusable modules, so I can use them in future projects and can more easily maintain them. One of those modules is a UserModel. The implementation of the UserModel creates a table in the database, seeds a demo-user to the table, does authentication...
I want to keep the Model as pure as possible only adding a username and password as variables

```
class UserModel  {
    var userName: String
    var password : String 

    some functions...
}
```

My plan was then to create a User model in my project inheriting from UserModel :

```
class User : UserModel {
   var language : String
   var companyName : String
   ...
}
```

adding variables specific to this project (and use migrations here to add the extra fields to the database, overwrite the demo-user seeding function...

So far so good, seems logic and a good way to me.

HOWEVER Vapor requires me to adopt the Content protocol for UserModel

```
final class UserModel {
   ...
}
```

and adopting to that protocol requires me to make the UserModel class final! (or I'll end up with a compiler error: *Protocol 'RequestDecodable' requirement 'decodeRequest' cannot be satisfied by a non-final class ('UserModel') because it uses 'Self' in a non-parameter, non-result type position*

So I end up with :

```
final class UserModel
```

from which I can not inherit

Can someone point me to an approach that is not inheritance where I can still keep a simple reusable UserModel but add specific fields for this project...
I'm looking for a way to implement this in a nice, structured way not a hack... (unless it is an acceptable hack ;) )

Comment: A protocol is one solution another one is to forget the whole idea and create a new User class for each new project. With the later I mean, is it worth it to try to create this reusable design or are you adding extra work for very little gain?

Comment: It is worth is, the user class with authentication was quite complex to make, it can already be used in 2 upcoming projects. As for now I will just keep a copy of this 'clean' model and start adapting it for this project